# How can I output a matplotlib figure to a shapefile?

Tags: matplotlib, shapefile

I want to create a contour plot with matlibplot and generate a shapefile from it so that I can use it in QGIS to display it.

Though it is possible to plot a map with matplotlib and then overlay with my contour plot, the choices of map sources are limited. It would be easier to export the contour plot in a shapefile and loaded in QGIS with a customized map.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you already have a look at [Mayavi](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/) for more plotting functionalities?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [contour plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/contour/) available in QGIS, and it is based on the contouring functions of matplotlib. It's still a little bit buggy but hopefully that will be corrected in the future.